# ESP-IDF add external library / component: "project command is not scriptable"

Tags: cmake, esp32, esp-idf

I'm trying to force the esp-idf build system to make such trivial thing as adding external library to the application.
It is completely straightforward in plain CMake but for some reason it is not working in esp-idf awkward ecosystem.

The project structure is like below:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── components
│   │   ├── DummyLib
│   │   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │   │   ├── test.cpp
│   │   │   └── test.h
│   │   └── DummyLibComponent
│   │       └── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── main
│       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       └── mm01.c
└── esp-idf

6 directories, 7 files
```

app/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

set(EXTRA_COMPONENT_DIRS "components")

include($ENV{IDF_PATH}/tools/cmake/project.cmake)
project(app)
```

app/main/CMakeLists.txt:

```
idf_component_register(SRCS "mm01.c"
    INCLUDE_DIRS "."
    REQUIRES
        DummyLibComponent
)
```

app/main/app.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test.h"

void app_main(void)
{
    int ret = test_component();
}
```

app/components/DummyLib/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)                                                                                                          
project(DummyLib)
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC
    test.cpp
)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
    .
)
```

app/components/DummyLib/test.cpp:

```
#include "test.h"

int test_component()
{
    return 2+3;
}
```

app/components/DummyLib/test.h:

```
int test_component();
```

app/components/DummyLibComponent/CMakeLists.txt:

```
idf_component_register(
        INCLUDE_DIRS ../DummyLib # Not sure where should it point? To the include referenced by the lib or by relative path?        REQUIRES DummyLib
)

add_subdirectory(../DummyLib DummyLib)

target_link_libraries(${COMPONENT_LIB} INTERFACE DummyLib)
```

Directory tree:

esp-idf    <- here goes the esp-idf repo which is not included here

app         <- here is the application created using the 'create-project' command. It builds normally when no additional components are defined.

app/components    <- this directory is setup in 'EXTRA_COMPONENT_DIRS'

app/components/DummyLib  <- any static library that works normally in plain CMake

app/components/DummyLibComponent   <- a component that wraps the DummyLib to make i work with the esp-idf ecosystem

For this setup when I try to build the app using `idf.py build` it fails with that errors:

```
idf.py build                                                      
Executing action: all (aliases: build)
Running ninja in directory <PATH_TO_PROJECT>/app/build
Executing "ninja all"...
[0/1] Re-running CMake...-- Building ESP-IDF components for target esp32s3
CMake Error at <PATH_TO_PROJECT>/esp-idf/tools/cmake/component.cmake:224 (message):
  CMake Warning (dev) at build_properties.temp.cmake:8:

    Syntax Warning in cmake code at column 51

  

    Argument not separated from preceding token by whitespace.

  Call Stack (most recent call first):

    <PATH_TO_PROJECT>/esp-idf/tools/cmake/scripts/component_get_requirements.cmake:3 (include)

  This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

  

  CMake Error at
  <PATH_TO_PROJECT>/app/components/DummyLib/CMakeLists.txt:2
  (project):

    project command is not scriptable

  Call Stack (most recent call first):

    <PATH_TO_PROJECT>/esp-idf/tools/cmake/scripts/component_get_requirements.cmake:106 (include)
    <PATH_TO_PROJECT>/esp-idf/tools/cmake/scripts/component_get_requirements.cmake:124 (__component_get_requirements)
```

What is wrong with this setup?
What does 'poject command is not scriptable' mean?
What is the proper way to add EXTERNAL library without modifying it?

Comment: ESP-IDF treats **every subdirectory** of `components/` as a **component**, thus expecting to find a call to `idf_component_register` in their `CMakeLists.txt`. But your `components/DummyLib/CMakeLists.txt` doesn't contain that call. If you want to create non-component `CMakeLists.txt`, then do not place it into `components/` subdirectory. You could create your library e.g. under `app/components/DummyLibComponent/src/`, so the script `app/components/DummyLibComponent/CMakeLists.txt` could include it via `add_subdirectory(src)`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev your suggestion fixes the problem. At the moment Iv got the `DummyLib` outside the `component` directory. It compiles but will not link because of undefined reference to `test_component()`. The library is built. The object contains the function. The library is missing from the linker command line. Not sure why. Tried creating basic component without external dependency as described in the docs but it fails with same reason.

Comment: if you have a new problem, write a new question post with a [mre] of that problem

Comment: `target_link_libraries(${COMPONENT_LIB} INTERFACE DummyLib)` - This links with DummyLib all users of the component, but not the component itself. Instead, use PUBLIC or PRIVATE linkage.

Comment: The `undefined reference` showed up because the library is CPP and the main app where the function was called is plain C. *facepalm*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error

> project command is not scriptable

means that given command (`project` in your case) is from the list of [project commands](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-commands.7.html#project-commands), which shouldn't be used in the [scripting mode of CMake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#run-a-script) (`cmake -P </path/to/script>`). While you write the `CMakeLists.txt` which is normally processed in project mode (`cmake </path/to/source/dir>`), ESP-IDF actually has **two passes**:

1. Firstly ESP-IDF iterates over all components directories, every component's `CMakeLists.txt` is processed in the **scripting mode**, until it calls a specific function. This pass is needed for collect information about components.
2. Then ESP-IDF processes every components' `CMakeLists.txt` in **project mode**.

That is, until a component' `CMakeLists.txt` calls a ESP-IDF specific function, it shouldn't use project-only commands.

The usual function which terminates scripting mode in ESP-IDF processing is `idf_component_register`. But there are other "terminating" functions.

Your library `app/components/DummyLib` is located in the component's directory, so ESP-IDF tries read its `CMakeLists.txt` in a scripting mode. This is why you get the error.

You could move the library files into some other directory. E.g., into `app/components/DummyLibComponent/src/`. In that case you may adjust `app/components/DummyLibComponent/CMakeLists.txt` to use new location of the library:

```
idf_component_register(
        INCLUDE_DIRS ../DummyLib # Not sure where should it point? To the include referenced by the lib or by relative path?
)

add_subdirectory(src)

target_link_libraries(${COMPONENT_LIB} PUBLIC DummyLib)
```

---

Alternatively, you may create [pure CMake component](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/v4.2/esp32/api-guides/build-system.html#writing-pure-cmake-components). Its scripting mode is terminated by `add_library` call. So make sure you have no project command before that call:

```
# app/components/DummyLib/CMakeLists.txt
# 
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC
    test.cpp
)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
    .
)
```

In that case `app/components/DummyLibComponent/CMakeLists.txt` is not needed.